# Blank Download Page [PHP]

Tags: php, html, linux, apache, .htaccess

Recently moved a site over to a new server and now for some reason the download page is no longer downloading the purchased files.

When the download page is reached it is simply blank. I have changed the filename directory to use home/mastetu8 instead of home/mastvoic which was the last directory. Any idea on why the page is blank when trying to download?

Here is the download_process.php file currently running this piece:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php require_once('../Connections/admin.php'); ?>
<?php
$orders_id = $_GET['orderid'];
$id = $_GET['id'];

mysql_select_db($database_admin, $admin);
$query_rsOrdersDetail = "SELECT * FROM orders_detail LEFT JOIN media ON     orders_detail.product_id = media.sortorder WHERE orders_detail.orders_id = '$orders_id' AND orders_detail.id = '$id'";
$rsOrdersDetail = mysql_query($query_rsOrdersDetail, $admin) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsOrdersDetail = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsOrdersDetail);
$totalRows_rsOrdersDetail = mysql_num_rows($rsOrdersDetail);

// CHECK DOWNLOAD COUNT
if ($row_rsOrdersDetail['downloadcount'] <= 3) {

$filename_hires =     '/home/mastetu8/public_html'.$row_rsOrdersDetail['filename_hires'];

if (file_exists($filename_hires)) {
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename_hires));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename_hires));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($filename_hires);

// UPDATE DOWNLOAD COUNTER
$downloadcount_new = $row_rsOrdersDetail['downloadcount'] + 1;

mysql_select_db($database_admin, $admin);
mysql_query("UPDATE orders_detail SET downloadcount='$downloadcount_new'     WHERE id = '$id' AND orders_id = '$orders_id'", $admin) or     die(mysql_error());

}


}
?>
```

Comment: It's probably crashed for some reason, but the output buffering is preventing you from seeing the problem. Have you checked your PHP error logs?

Comment: (You've got SQL injection vulnerabilities in this code, by the way - don't go live until they are fixed. Ideally you need to migrate to a better database library, so you can use parameter binding).

Comment: I also see no self-created error messages like 'download count is above 3', or 'could not find file'. Also things that might help indicate where the problem lays.

Comment: Try removing `header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename_hires));`. You new server may or may not be gziping the file and because of that content-length value will be incorrect.